# Sort a knockoutjs model computed field

Tags: knockout.js

How can I sort an observableArray with a computed field in a knockoutjs model? I want to sort with the computed field. Here is the field:

```
self.filteredCases = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.cases(), function (onecase) {
            return ((self.eventFilter() == 1 && onecase.Status() == self.statusFilter())
                || (self.eventFilter() != 1 && onecase.Status() == self.eventFilter())
                || ((self.eventFilter() == 1 && self.statusFilter() == 0)
                    && (onecase.Status() == 1 || onecase.Status() == 2 || onecase.Status() == 3 || onecase.Status() == 4))
                );
        });
    });
```

So I want to sort only the filtered items, not all the items. The items sort is working, but it seems that ko.computed hasn't got sort method.

I have more columns, here it is one filter method:

```
self.orderById = function (direction) {
    self.cases.sort(function (left, right) { //Working
    //self.filteredCases().sort(function (left, right) { //Do nothing
        return direction ?
            left.CaseId() > right.CaseId() ? 1 : -1
            : left.CaseId() < right.CaseId() ? 1 : -1;
    });
};
```

Please advice,

Comment: You probably have like self.filteredCases.sort and need self.filteredCases().sort

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward. Just sort your filtered array.

```
self.filteredCases = ko.computed(function () {
    var filter =  ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.cases(), function (onecase) {
        return ((self.eventFilter() == 1 && onecase.Status() == self.statusFilter())
            || (self.eventFilter() != 1 && onecase.Status() == self.eventFilter())
            || ((self.eventFilter() == 1 && self.statusFilter() == 0)
                && (onecase.Status() == 1 || onecase.Status() == 2 || onecase.Status() == 3 || onecase.Status() == 4))
            );
    });

    return filter.sort();

    //Optionally, you can pass a function to sort,
    //Which takes a left and right parameter
    //And returns -1/1 for before/after
    return filter.sort(function(left, right) {
        return left.Status() > right.Status() ? 1 : -1;
    })
});
```

Comment: This could be a solution, but I have more columns, and all of the columns can be sorted, not just Status. I filtered cases with Status, but should be order them by another properties (Id, Name, Owner, Date etc...).

Comment: Then replace `Status` inside the sort method with whatever property you are sorting by. Or use another observable to track the property you want to sort, and then use *that* in the sort method. It's pretty flexible.

Comment: Tyrsius thank you for ideas. What about sorting is changing, but filtering is not? Then your sort in filter method won't work.

Comment: Actually it will, because the computed will still have a dependency on the sort property (`Status` in my example). So that is only the sorted property changes, the whole thing will still update. If you want to avoid refiltering, you could split the sort into a second `computed` which only sorted the `filteredCases`.